# Regexfield insufficient to validate text input (Django form)

Tags: regex, django, unicode, django-forms

In a Django form, users set their usernames. The username field in the form is defined like so:

```
    username = forms.RegexField(max_length=50,regex=r'^[\w.@ +-]+$',
            help_text=_("Required. 50 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                          "@/./+/-/_ only."),
            error_messages={
                'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                             "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})
```

Validation occurs when the regular expression is matched, otherwise not. For instance, setting the username `Bender*` is invalid, whereby `Bender@` is valid.

I've noticed that my form throws a nasty error if the user enters arabic or persian text, instead of elegantly invalidating it. E.g. if one tries `العربی` as the username, the following is thrown:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /keep_username/

'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why doesn't this piece of text invalidate like normally (and What can I do to fix this)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegexField can take a complied regular expression as well as a string. Shall we try it this way?

```
import re

regex = re.compile('^[\w.@ +-]+$',re.UNICODE)

class Myclass(models.Model):

     username = forms.RegexField(max_length=50,regex=regex,
            help_text=_("Required. 50 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                          "@/./+/-/_ only."),
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can handle it with [`RegexValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.RegexValidator)

for the `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class FooBar(forms.Form):
    username_validator = RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@ +-]+$', 
                                        "This value may contain only letters, "
                                        "numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters
    username = forms.CharField(validators=[username_validator])
```

or inside your `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class FooBar(models.Model):
    username_validator = RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@ +-]+$', 
                                        "This value may contain only letters, "
                                        "numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[username_validator])
```